# PyQt .ui в .py возникает проблема

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt5

Установил pyqt5 и qt Designer. Сделал тестовую программу, после чего нужно было перевести ее в python код. Начал искать как это сделать, там говорится о файле pyqtc5.exe я его не нашел, но нашел pyqtc5.bat.  Дальше, как сказано в туторе, я перешел в ту папку, написал команду но выдает такую ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я находился в директории, где и pyqtc5.bat, так же туда закинул файл с тестовой программой.

Comment: не совсем к теме , но почему бы не воспользоваться пакетом "анаконда" там как раз pyqt есть. Не придеться танцевать с бубном выискивая батники.

Comment: @timob256 есть под рукой гайд, где все расписано по этой теме?

Comment: Вообще-то вам нужен `pyuic5.exe`.  `pyuic5.exe test.ui -o test.py  -x` . Где он у вас лежит и прописан ли к нему доступ - это другой вопрос. у меня он находится по пути: `E:\Python\Scripts\pyuic5.exe`

Comment: попробуйте  [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37419138/is-qt-designer-bundled-with-anaconda)

Comment: С анакондой все проще там ненужно гайдов.

Comment: Просто я еще столкнулся с тем что стал читать [python для сложных задач наука о данных и машинное обучение](https://www.piter.com/product_by_id/109260934) и чтоб не мучатся качать по одной библиотеке _(которая ещё подумает ляжет ли она или нет )_ я просто установил **Анаконду и получил все ведущие математические библиотеки и Qt :3**

Comment: @S.Nick У меня такого нету, я уже искал

Comment: По-моему `pip install pyqt5-tools` вам должен помочь.  https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/

Comment: @S.Nick вообще, я уж пробовал это ставить, но с ним она не идет. Попробовал поставить qt через консоль и файл появился

Comment: Вот гайд, ставишь анаконду --> прописываешь в path `\Anaconda3\Library\bin` --> запускаешь qt Designer (лежит \Anaconda3\Library\bin) -->сохраняешь куда хочешь --> заходишь туда через cmd прописываешь  `pyuic5.bat имя_файла.ui -o имя_выходного_файла.py`

Answer (score 0):

**ВОт так :3**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Команда :

```
С:\Games\Anaconda3_work>C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\pyuic.bat C:\Games\Anaconda3_work\ untitled.ui -o C:\Games\Anaconda3_work\untitled.py
```

не отработала , но и ошибок не выдала.

---

Ставил Anacond-y третью , с всеми Qt библиотеками.
В анаконде designer.exe  находиться ..\Anaconda3\Library\bin.

Сам все делаю по книге [Python3 и PyQt5 Разработка приложений Прохоренок Н., Дронов В.](http://www.bhv.ru/books/book.php?id=193962)

Как раз там написано.

> Для генерации питон программы выполним команду : pyuic5.bat MyForm.ui -o ui_MyForm.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

После установки Anacond-ы обязательно в "переменные среды " добавить расположение анаконды, точнее её исполнительных файлов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

П.с.
*На анаконду перешёл потому что не так просто устанавливаются библиотеки как пишут в книгах (со зависимость библиотек очень огромна и не всегда удаётся загрузить и правильно установить библиотеку)*